# Importing python files in another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-import

I have a folder of this file structure:

```
Desktop
    tech_comp
       googledash.csv
       viz.py
       sql_load.py

       company_AL
           __init__.py
           functionloads.py
           decisionplans.py
           niches.py
           actions.py
```

I am working with `VScode` in the following path as described above: `C:\Users\username\Desktop\tech_comp\company_AL`

I have written a bunch of `list` in the `decisionplans.py` now I am trying to load it in the `actions.py` I am working with. Here is what I did.

```
from company_AL import decisionplans
```

It does not show `errors` in the `compiler` but when I run I get the following.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'company_AL'
```

I do not intend to publish it as online as this is a private project, please how do I handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your startup location? Since it's imported by relative paths (unless found in import paths) you need to consider this when importing.

Comment: What do you mean? Not clear

Comment: When you run your script, in which folder do you execute from? If you open a terminal, and you navigate to a folder, to run `python <some script.py>`, which folder are you in? : ) (VScode uses the same principle of a "working directory" or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many solutions to solve your problem :

## 1. Add compagn_AL folder to your PYTHON_PATH

It depends of your OS but there is tutorials that explians better than me

## 2. Change the PATH for your script

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../') # or "C:\Users\username\Desktop\tech_comp\"
```

and then

```
from compagny_AL import decisionplans
```

## 3. Import it directly (not recommended)

You can just

```
import decisinplans
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do `import decisionplans` or `from .company_AL import decisionplans` because you are already in the `company_AL`.